# Upper rectangle area sum to approximate 1/x between $1\leq x\leq 3$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, summation

I am trying to figure out how to use rectangles to approximate the area under the curve $1/x$ on the interval $[1,3]$ using $n$ rectangle that covers the region under the curve as such.

Here is what I did, I am looking at sum of terms of area of rectangles whose width is $\frac{2}{n}$ and length is $ \frac{1}{1+\frac{2}{n}(k-1)}$ where $1\leq k\leq n$.

So I want to evaluate this series as $n\to\infty$, $\displaystyle \sum^n_{k=1} \frac{2}{n}\bigg(\frac{1}{1+\frac{2}{n}(k-1)}\bigg)$. I have been playing around with this sum for a couple hours now and going no where.

Can someone push me in the right direction? Should I partition the interval differently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Partitioning the integral into equal subintervals will give you a very difficult sum to evaluate.  Try using the partition
$$1\,,\ q\,,\ q^2\,,\ q^3\,,\ldots,\ q^n$$
where $q^n=3$.  The sum is then very easy.

Note that the question as you have asked it does not require you to obtain the area by letting $n\to\infty$.  This would actually be rather problematic.  You can find the limit by using L'Hopital's rule, but only if you assume you already know that the derivative of $\ln x$ is $1/x$, which would make the whole problem a bit pointless to say the least, a circular argument to say the worst.

Comment: I see, what I want to do ultimately is to bound the $B_n<$area($\frac{1}{x},1,3)<U_n$ where $U_n$ is the sum of  area of $n$ many rectangles that covers the area of the curve and $B_n$ are areas of $n$ many rectangles that's below the curve. And show they converge to the samething and hence arrive at the area$(1/x,1,3)$. I was thinking I probably should use a different partition but I didnt know which one to use. Thank you for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

Your sum is equal to $T_n := 2 \sum_{1 \leq k \leq n} \frac{1}{n + 2(k - 1)},$ so there is reason to believe that there might be a connection to the [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)). It will be enough to evaluate the convergence of $T_n$ when $n = 2r.$ Indeed, let $S_n := \sum_{1 \leq k \leq n} \frac{1}{n}.$ Then
$$T_{2 r} = \sum_{1 \leq k \leq 2 r} \frac{1}{r + k - 1} = S_{3 r - 1} - S_{r - 1} = \log(3 r - 1) + \gamma + \frac{1}{2(3 r - 1)} - \\
 \log(r - 1) - \gamma - \frac{1}{2 (r - 1)} + O(\frac{1}{r^2}) = \log \frac{3 r - 1}{r - 1} + O(\frac{1}{r}),$$
which clearly converges to $\log 3$ as $n \to \infty.$ To see why this is enough to yield the convergence of the entire sequence, note that
$$T_{2 r} - T_{2 r + 1} = 2 \sum_{1 \leq k \leq 2 r} (\frac{1}{2 r + 2(k - 1)} - \frac{1}{2r + 2(k - 1) + 1}) - \frac{2}{6 r + 1},$$
the first part of which can be bound by the tail of the [alternating harmonic series](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlternatingHarmonicSeries.html), which is convergent, thus its tail is also convergent to $0$ and clearly the last term is convergent to $0$ as well. Having established this, we can safely deduce the convergence of the initial sequence to $3.$ I hope this helps. :)

P.S.: In fact, if we denote the alternating series partial sums by $A_n := \sum_{1 \leq k \leq n} \frac{(-1)^{k + 1}}{k} = S_{2 n} - S_n,$ we can see that
$$T_{2 r} - T_{2 r + 1} = 2(A_{2 r - 1} - A_{6 r - 1}) - \frac{2}{6 r + 1} = \\
2 (S_{4 r - 2} - S_{2 r - 1} - S_{12 r - 2} + S_{6 r - 1}) - \frac{2}{6 r + 1},$$
which yields an expression for $T_{2r + 1}$ simply in terms of the partial sums of the harmonic series, namely
$$T_{2 r + 1} = S_{3 r - 1} - S_{r - 1} - 2 (S_{4 r - 2} - S_{2 r - 1} - S_{12 r - 2} + S_{6 r - 1}) + \frac{2}{6 r + 1},$$
however rather unpleasant to look at.

Comment: Thank you, this seems very interesting I will look into it!

Comment: You're most welcome! :)